# Automatically generated sitemap on Google App Engine

Tags: python, web-services, google-app-engine, python-2.7, web

Okay so I know there are already some questions about this topic but I don't find any to be specific enough. I want to have a script on my site that will automatically generate my sitemap.xml (or save it somewhere). I know how to upload files and have my site set up on http://sean-behan.appspot.com with Python 2.7. How do I setup the script that will generate the sitemap and if possible please reference the code. Just ask if you need more info. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can have outside services automatically generate them for you by traversing your site.

One such service is at http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/details-sean-behan.appspot.com.html

Alternatively, you can serve your own xml file based on the URL's you want to appear in your site. In which case, see Tim Hoffman's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can't point you to code, as I don't know how your site is structured or what templating env you use, does your site structure include static pages etc...

The basics are if you have code that can pull together a list of dictionaries that contain the metadata about each page you want in your sitemap then you are half way there.

The use a templating language (or straight python ) that generates an xml file as per sitemap.org spec.

Now you have two choices, dynamically serve this output as requested, or store it in the datastore if when compressed it is less than 1MB, or write it to google cloud storage, then server it's contents when /sitemap.xml is requested.  You will then set up a cron task to regenerate your cached sitemap once a day (or whatever frequency is appropriate).